# React router and nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am confused about how to create the following (really simple) route structure.

I have an app that has a top-level route for the Login component:

[image]

and another top-level route for the app itself (let's call it the Home component):

[image]

now, the Home component has a header, a sidebar, and the main space for the child views.

The Login component should be shown at `/login` path; that's simple enough. But what confuses me is that I want the `/` path to show the Home component with a particular child component (let's call it Welcome) in the main view. Also, most of the other routes that I can think of should render child components inside the Home component.

So, to reiterate:

path `/` renders the Home component with the Welcome component inside it

path `/foo` renders the Home component with the Foo component inside it

...

path `/login` renders the Login component

It feels like the structure that I am thinking about is:

```
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}>
        <IndexRoute component={Welcome}>
        <Route path='foo' component={Foo}/>
    </IndexRoute>
    <Route path='login' component={Login}/>
  </Route>
```

but this is clearly wrong. What would be the correct way to implement this routing structure?

Comment: Sounds like  you should have your Login component inside of your Welcome component. Create a render function inside of your Welcome Component to either render the Login or the welcome component depending if they had logged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a good solution, give it a try.

```
<Route component={App}>
  <Route path="/" component={Home}>
    <IndexRoute component={Welcome}/>
    <Route path="/foo" component={Foo}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Yay! That works perfectly! Thank you for the solution.